# How to rotate a clock hand around a point with createjs

Tags: javascript, rotation, html5-canvas, createjs, tween.js

I have a clock hand that i want to rotate. right now it rotates the whole image around the 0,0 point of the image. How would i rotate around the dot on the clock hand? Can you choose the registration point that it should rotate around?

my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yhx94cuf/23/

```
    var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);
var image = new Image();
var image2 = new Image();
image.src = "http://paulrhayes.com/experiments/clock/images/minuteHand.png"
image2.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Analogue_clock_face.svg/1024px-Analogue_clock_face.svg.png"
image.onload = Clock;

function Clock() {
    clockContainer = new createjs.Container();
    clockBack = new createjs.Bitmap(image2)
    clockHand = new createjs.Bitmap(image)
    clockBack.x = 40;
    clockBack.y = 180;
    clockHand.x = -30;
    clockHand.y = 100;
    clockHand.scaleX = clockHand.scaleY = 1.20;
    clockHand.scaleX = clockHand.scaleY = 1.20;
    clockBack.scaleX = clockBack.scaleY = 0.30;
    clockBack.scaleX = clockBack.scaleY = 0.30;

    clockContainer.addChild(clockBack, clockHand);
    stage.addChild(clockContainer)
    createjs.Tween.get(clockHand, { loop: false }).to({ rotation: 360 }, 5000);
}

function tick(event) {
    stage.update();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regX` and `regY` to change the registration (0,0) point of the display object. You'll have to adjust your `x`/`y` values accourdingly.

http://jsfiddle.net/yhx94cuf/24/